# Check if control is on screen

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

How do I check if a control/DisplayObject is on screen? This means it is displayed on screen so no scrolling needs to be done.

Example: I have several controls on a form. The size of the form exceeds the screen length/width. As a result I need scrollbars. How do I check if a control is on screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a less elegant solution, but if no one else answers, you can try to do this:

Check X and Y (or just Y if you are interested in height) of the component you want to verify is on-screen or off-screen.

Then compare that to the total height of the application or container of the component.

Comment: After some serious researching this might be the only option :/

Comment: Have you tried the Adobe Flex forum for this as well? They are great at answering tricky questions about Flex.